# How to get client IP address via Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

I just started using Google Cloud Endpoints on GAE and for one of the API methods need to know the IP address of the client.

Using webapp2 I would have used self.request.remote_addr but I can't seem to find anything similar when using the endpoints API.

What would the suggested method be to get the client remote IP address?

Comment: try: os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]

Comment: Of course you're right. I was just about to check to see if there was something in the environment variables I could use.

Answer (score 0):

As @voscausa mentioned:

```
os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Endpoints are implemented using WebApp2 so you can have access to the request state object

```
remote_address = (self.request_state.remote_address if self.request_state else '')
```